# Duplicate symbols (project using library using same library as project)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

`A` is static library.
`B` is static library that uses the `A` library.
`C` is application that uses both the `A` and the `B` libraries.

Problem with duplicate symbols in `C` is obvious.

What is proper (official) solution to avoid this problem. I really want to use `A` in `B`. All `A`, `B`, `C` are mine projects in one Xcode workspace.

Comment: Static libraries are compiled directly into the executable/library, so you don't need to link `C` with `A`. Use `A` in `B`, and use `B` in your application, but don't link `A` directly with your application. Just include the headers from `A`; you don't need to link with it separately since it's already included in `B`.

Comment: Why dont you expose the header file of library A only in C and not include it in your workspace? Library B is compiled with library A so you must be able to use A in C without including it separately.
PS: I have not tried it, its a suggestion only.

Comment: Thank you. If you switch your comment to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PartiallyFinite answered my question. Unfortunately in comment. As he does not respond to make his comment answer that I can accept, I'm quoting him to close this question.

"Static libraries are compiled directly into the executable/library, so you don't need to link `C` with `A`. Use `A` in `B`, and use `B` in your application, but don't link `A` directly with your application. Just include the headers from `A`; you don't need to link with it separately since it's already included in `B`."

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurs with your imports ie

```
#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"
#import "C.h"
```

In interfaces of each other.. Better way to do to avoid the scenario is not to import `.h` file in the interface class instead you can easily do

```
@class A;
@class B;
@class C;
```

in the interface, and import the respective `.h` class in the `.m` file.

So it should look like this

In `A.h` class

```
@class B;
@class C;

@interface A : NSObject

@end
```

In `A.m` class

```
#import "B.h"
#import "C.h"
@implementation A

@end
```

Comment: The premise of this answer is wrong. `#import` (as opposed to `#include`) makes sure that each header is only imported *once and just once*. This is not the cause of the problem, linking seems to be. On the other hand, the suggestions of using `@class X;` in headers as opposing to importing the whole header is a good one (but do note that sometimes importing headers from headers is unavoidable, such as when inheriting from another class or using externally defined protocols).

Comment: This is not a wrong answer, this solves the problem of Duplicate entries smoothly and too efficient.. @rsanchezsaez have you tried the solution that proves that it is wrong ?

Comment: I clarified a bit my comment. I didn't want to be harsh because I think this answer has actually a good suggestion.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Downvote is definitely not the solution, you may choose to try to improve my answer rather..

Comment: @iphonic: Your question suggests that `#import` statements can *include* the same header twice and that this will cause problems at compilation time. This is not the case. See my edited first comment. So yes, sorry but it is a wrong answer because: a) it contains non-factual information and b) the suggestion (more of a good coding practice than anything) solves a problem different from the one stated in the question.